# Calculating the fractional part of a number inside a `serde_json::Value::Number`

Tags: rust, serde-json

My goal is to take a `serde_json::Value::Number` and if the number it contains is represented as a non-integral value with a fractional part of `0.0`, convert it into a `serde_json::Value::Number` containing the equivalent integer representation.

I have the following snippet that attempts this:

```rust
use serde_json::{Number, Value};

fn trim_trailing_zeros(val: Value) -> Value {
    match val {
        Value::Number(n) => Value::Number({
            match n.as_f64() {
                Some(m) => {
                    if m.fract() == 0.0 {
                        Number::from(m as i64)
                    } else {
                        n
                    }
                }
                _ => n,
            }
        }),
        var => var,
    }
}
```

The problem with this is if the number can't be accurately converted to an `f64` as this [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f0dfb9b403437ff2fa3bf8202fd386de) link shows, the output is not equal to the input.  This seems insurmountable because the field of a `Number` is private, so I can only use [these few methods](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/value/struct.Number.html#implementations), and one that seems unavoidable is `as_f64`.  The others seem to not be of use at all in this problem.

Can anyone think of another way to do this?  Is there some way I can convert a `Value::Number` into a string and try to parse it without loss of accuracy?

*Edit:*  As pointed out in the comments, first checking that the `Number` contains an `i64` or `f64` with `is_i64()` or `is_f64()` before attempting an `as_f64()` also could theoretically run into conversion issues.

Comment: It seems you can call `.is_f64()` which is only `true` if the value cannot be represented by an `i64` or `u64`. Doesn't that solve your problem since if it is `false` it won't have a fractional part?

Comment: Though you may still encounter problems since there are `f64`s with no fractional component that won't fit in a `i64`. Its not clear to me what the purpose of this is, so I don't know what you'd want to do about that.

Comment: Wait, isn't my problem the opposite?  There are `i64`s that can't be converted to an `f64`.  So maybe if I checked that `is_i64()` is false first, then I could call `.as_f64()` without loss?  I was confused at first by the descriptions and examples of these methods, but this might be the solution.

Comment: Both problems exist: there are u64s that can't be represented precisely by f64s and there are integer f64s that can't be represented by u64s. See a demonstration on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e68d031ddfb90c5bf20883b1eb11c872).

Comment: Note that `is_i64` is false if a decimal point exists, even if the fractional part is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is using the `arbitrary_precision` feature of `serde_json`. That feature stores the number as a string, and then you can do the parsing yourself:

```ini
[dependencies]
serde_json = { version = "*", features = ["arbitrary_precision"] }
```

```rust
Value::Number(n) => Value::Number({
    if let Some((whole, fract)) = n.as_str().split_once('.') {
        if fract.as_bytes().iter().all(|&b| b == b'0') {
            let i: i64 = whole.parse().unwrap();
            Number::from(i)
        } else {
            n
        }
    } else {
        let i: i64 = n.as_str().parse().unwrap();
        Number::from(i)
    }
}),
```

[playground](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#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)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deserialize a floating point number without loss you should consider using `rust_decimal::Decimal`.  You didn't provide a lot of code, but for your object you can do something like

```
struct Item {
    name: String,
    price: Decimal,
}
```

and then from

```
let data = r#"
        {
            "name": "Apple",
            "price": "2.99"
        }"#;


let item: Item = serde_json::from_str(data)?;
```

You can then differentiate integers and non-integers with `.is_integer`, pick apart the fraction parts and integral parts  after the deserialization from that with `.round` and `.fract()` (or some of the others like `floor` and `ceil` depending on your rules)

Comment: That's not really the problem.  I've already got a `serde_json::Value` with some `Number`s but I don't know or have any control over what's contained in the `Number`.  Put another way, I'm constrained by this enum: https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/src/serde_json/number.rs.html#26-34